# Comment form entries Avatar?

Tags: comments

Is it possible to get the commenter's avatar through the comment:entries tag?

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="asc" limit="9" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}
                    <li>
                        <figure class="profile-photo"><img src="{if avatar_url}{exp:imgsizer:size src='{avatar_url}' width='120' height='120'}{sized}{/exp:imgsizer:size}{if:else}{site_url}img/assets/default_avatar.png{/if}" alt=""></figure><aside>
                            <div class="meta-info">
                                <p><a href="#">{name}</a> <time>{comment_date format="%Y %m %d"}</time></p><i class="icon-review"></i>
                            </div><!--meta-info-->
                            <article>
                                <p>{exp:stringy:striptags allowed_tags=""}{comment}{/exp:stringy:striptags}</p>
                            </article>
                        </aside>
                    </li>
                    {paginate}
                    {pagination_links}
                    <div class="pagination">
                        <p>Page {pagination_page_number} of {total_pages}:</p><!--
                        --><ul>
                            {previous_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="prev"><i class="icon-left-arrow"></i></a></li>{/previous_page}<!--
                            -->{page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>{/page}<!--
                            -->{next_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="next"><i class="icon-right-arrow"></i></a></li>{/next_page}
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--pagination-->
                    {/pagination_links}
                    {/paginate}
                {/exp:comment:entries}
```

Here is my current code for the latest comments, it doesn't seem to be grabbing the member's avatar?

Any ideas?

Thanks
All the best
-Graham.

Comment: If you remove the imgsizer plugin tag and just replace with the avatar_url does it output anything?

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for getting back to me, Unfortunately not, I've tried stripping it down to the bare bones, even querying inside the entries loop but having no luck.

Comment: Try just using this and see if anything is outputted.

{exp:comment:entries}{if avatar}{avatar_url}{/if}{/exp:comment:entries}

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately

Comment: Try removing the if statement. If that doesn't work what version of EE are you using? When you used the code above, did the comment text show? Are you certain the users commenting have Avatars?

Comment: I am currently running EE 2.9.2, Comments and everything else comes through fine, members do currently have avatars: It seems I can only use these tags: 

comment
comment_date
email
location
name
url
url_as_author
url_or_email
url_or_email_as_author
url_or_email_as_link

Comment: Ok so I've just seen that the author didn't have an avatar, but every other member has one. After uploading an avatar to the author all of the comments now have his avatar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `exp:comment:entries` tag out of the `exp:channel:entries` tag and supply either the `entry_id` or `url_title` of the entry you want. The `avatar_url` variable is being overwritten by the channel:entries variable.

```
{exp:comment:entries entry_id="XXX" sort="asc" limit="9" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}
   <img src="{avatar_url}" />
{/exp:comment:entries}
```